# PostgreSQL problema al conectar desde Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring, jpa, pgadmin, spring-tool-suite

tengo un proyecto con Spring Boot en Spring Tool Suite y estoy tratando de conectar a una base PostgreSQL. La conexión la maneja el mismo Spring Tool por medio de una dependencia. En mi máquina tengo instalado PostgreSQL con pgAdmin. Al momento de ejecutar el servicio, la conexión me da el siguiente error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: El servidor requiere autenticación basada en contraseña, pero no se ha provisto ninguna contraseña.

application.properties

```
server.port=9898

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/demo
spring.datasource.data-username=postgres
spring.datasource.data-password=123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

En pgAdmin se creó el server con la contraseña especificada en el properties. No se que más puede estar faltar faltando.

Saludos y espero respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

[Como menciona la documentacion de Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database), esta es la manera en la que debes configurar las propiedades de conexion a la BD:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Tu problema esta en que lo has configurado como `data-username` y `data-password` en vez de solo `username` y `password`.